# Palindrome boolean not checking false

Tags: c++

For some reason my boolean is not checking false, can anyone help me figure out why? Also how would I go about making this program ignore spaces if it were a phrase (i.e. "never odd or even")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   string input;
   int i = 0;
   bool flag = true;
   int size = input.size();
   
   cin >> input;
   
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      if (input.at(i) != input.at(size - i - 1))
      {
         flag = false;  
      }   
   }   

   if (flag = true)
   {
      cout << "palindrome: " << input << endl;  
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "not a palindrome: " << input << endl;   
   }   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am looking at this on my phone so forgive me if I misread something. I would look at how you examine the letters at the end of the string. You need to check at size - 1 and work your way backward. Also, in the for loop, you don’t need to go until i is at the end of string, just to the halfway point.

Comment: I adjusted to only be half, but the not checking false issue still stands

Comment: Ignore my first few sentences in my previous comment. I meant to delete them but my phone is awful. In regards to your white space problem, there is a method that will replace characters in a string with different ones, such as replacing all “ “ with “”.

Comment: Got the spacing figured out thanks a ton for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer

You are getting the size of the string before the user has entered the string.

Change

```
int size = input.size();

cin >> input;
```

to

```
cin >> input:

int size = input.size();
```

### Previous answer

You are using a single = rather than two in the if statement.

Change

```
if (flag = true)
```

to

```
if (flag == true)
```

Comment: sadly it is still not checking false after that change

Comment: `if(flag == true)` is also still a bit overly-wordy since `flag` is a `bool`. You can just write `if(flag)`, although you might want a more descriptive variable name than `flag`.